# Image "height" automatically added in Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, content-builder

I use custom HTML for my email templates. When a new image is uploaded into an email there is always an image heigth populated in the code. In a two column responsive content block we have to delete "height" manually every time we build new emails.

Is there away to prevent the system from setting this value?

Thanks
Oliver

Comment: Have you disabled the "Scale to fit" option on the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Content Builder adds its own `<img src...>` tag with standard attributes. Everytime a new image is replaced or added using the UI this happens to be the case.

To resolve this behaviour you'd created a class and set it to the wrapping `<td>` or `<table>` since these HTML tags don't get affected by the UI

For example:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="ImageAuto"><img src="http://unsplash.it/g/600/400?text=BANNER" width="100%" border="0" alt="BANNER" style="display:block;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Above code, you can see the `<image>` tag being wrapped around `<td>` which won't be replaced or altered by the Content Builder UI. You can then use the class `ImageAuto` in your media query to handle the height of the image.

For example:

```
.ImageAuto img { 
          height: auto !important;
          width: 100% !important;
        }
```